# Code compiles but does not run completely. When the DoWhile loop is exited red error notes pop up

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class TipCalculator{

  static double Steak; 

  static double Ribs; 

  static double Salad; 

  static double Burger; 

  static double SoftDrink; 

  static double PintofBeer; 

  static double Wine; 

  static double Champagne;

  static int i; 

  static double [] Choice = new double [15]; 

  static double Subtotal; 

  static double Tax; 

  static double Tip; 

  static double Total; 

  public static void main (String args []){ 

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);  

    Ribs = 25; 

    Steak = 35; 

    Salad = 5; 

    Burger = 15; 

    SoftDrink = 2; 

    PintofBeer = 5; 

    Wine = 6; 

    Champagne = 9; 

    Tax = 1.13; 

    do {


      System.out.println("Please enter one of the following options, or enter 9 to go to your bill"); 
      System.out.println("1. 12 oz Striploin Steak "); 
      System.out.println("2. 16 oz Baby Back Ribs "); 
      System.out.println("3. Ceaser Salad "); 
      System.out.println("4. House Burger "); 
      System.out.println("5. Soft Drink "); 
      System.out.println("6. Wine "); 
      System.out.println("7. Champagne "); 

      Choice [i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    while (Choice [i] < 9);



    if (Choice [i] == 9){ 

      Subtotal = Choice[1] + Choice[2] + Choice[3] + Choice[4] + Choice[5] + Choice[6] + Choice[7] + Choice[8] + Choice[9] + Choice[10] + Choice[11] + Choice[12] + Choice[13] + Choice[14] + Choice[15];

      System.out.println("Your subtotal is " + Subtotal); 
    }

    System.out.println("Enter your tip percent"); 

    Tip = scan.nextInt(); 

    Total = ((Subtotal * Tax) * (Tip/10)); 

    System.out.println("Your total is " + Total); 
  } 


}
```

Comment: *red error notes pop up* - what do ya reckon, share it with us? or shall we be mind readers?

Comment: I'm goiing look into my crystal ball and make a prediction: the "red error" is something like "_variable i might not have been initialized_".  How did I do?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Don't know about that.  I copy-pasta the code into my IDE and no red swigglies.

Comment: I Tried. When i added the message it would refuse to post because it said it wasnt proper coding format, even when i made it into a comment lmao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access array index 15 (so the 16th element in array) which is technically not there as index start from 0. So the last index you can access is 14. Total elements are 15 as initialized by your code.

Change your line :

`Subtotal = Choice[1] + Choice[2] + Choice[3] + Choice[4] + Choice[5] + Choice[6] + Choice[7] + Choice[8] + Choice[9] + Choice[10] + Choice[11] + Choice[12] + Choice[13] + Choice[14] + Choice[15];`

To:

`Subtotal = Choice[0] + Choice[1] + Choice[2] + Choice[3] + Choice[4] + Choice[5] + Choice[6] + Choice[7] + Choice[8] + Choice[9] + Choice[10] + Choice[11] + Choice[12] + Choice[13] + Choice[14];`

This will get the flow rolling. (Although I will confess, the code is not doing what it is meant to be doing by just reading your code. But that is a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked as intended after, such a stupid fix can't believe i missed it. I was stressing cuz this was a warmup code and it wasnt working lmao.